# C# drag drop reselecting a picturebox to mve from form

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, picturebox

So i am having a project where i need to drag and drop different pictureboxes and make an existing copy of them to the form when i drag drop them. My problem is that i cannot move the selected "picture box" after it is created on the form. I would like to have an option where i can move any picturebox that is dragged not like dragging at a position and keeping it at that position.

```
    private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p = (PictureBox)sender;
            p.Tag = p.Location;
            downPoint = e.Location;
            p.Parent = this;
            p.BringToFront();

        }

    }
    private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        p = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p.Left += e.X - downPoint.X ;
            p.Top += e.Y - downPoint.Y ;


        }
    }
     private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        p = (PictureBox)sender;

        PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();


        Control c = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(p.Left -1, p.Top));
        if (c == null) c = this;
        Point newLoc = c.PointToClient(p.Parent.PointToScreen(p.Location));
        PB.Parent = c;
        PB.Location = newLoc;


       ;

        p.Parent.Controls.Add(PB); // <-- add new PB to the form!
        p.Location = (Point)p.Tag;
        // put the original back where it started:

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put the events to the new picturebox**

```
PB.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox_MouseMove);
PB.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picturebOX_MouseDown);
PB.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picturebOX_MouseUp);
```